# Can meta.joomla be used for appraising feature requests?

Tags: discussion

Just thinking out of the box. The ideas site (ideas.joomla.org) has sort of died. Would meta be a suitable place to people to be able to log feature requests for the CMS, Framework, possible even the new Issue Tracker? The up and down voting would be useful in determining interest in any particular feature (or even an "idea" for the project as a whole not specifically related to code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, Meta is only the place where we - as active users of the StackExchange site for Joomla! - discuss issues, policies and features for it (the StackExchange site).

For a more insightful look on meta read [What is "meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) that describes StackOverflows meta.

I think discussions about Joomla! should be done on Joomla! itself. The idea of how it would have been related on the voting system is interesting though.

Comment: This is the right of it. We're not partnered with Joomla!, so we don't have any sort of official lean in with regards to stuff that happens here. However, if you want to discuss things that you want to propose to them amongst the community here, I recommend that a chat room could be a good way to set it up, at least to start.